# Get real world time

Tags: java, android

I use this code for get **real world** time from internet:

```
        try
          {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( new HttpGet( "http://developer.yahooapis.com/TimeService/V1/getTime?appid=YahooDemo"));
            StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
            if( statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
              {
                ByteArrayOutputStream byteTimeStamp = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                httpResponse.getEntity().writeTo( byteTimeStamp);
                byteTimeStamp.close();
                String sTimeStamp = byteTimeStamp.toString(); // this data contains real world time, I now can parse it...
              }
             else
              httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().close();
          }
         catch( Exception e) {}
```

This code work perfectly. But it use yahoo-service and depends them availability.

I use second way with GPS-locations service, but this way work requires add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

This is not good idea.

I need another way for get real world time. Any ideas please.

Also I need get world time with millisecounds, if it possible.

Comment: Look at Java's Calendar class

Comment: I need REAL WORLD time, not time in current device. Most devices have different with real world time.

Comment: A device is always only going to be able to say what time it thinks it is, therefore you have to rely on some external provider that you trust to report the real time. You just need to find a provider that you think is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is using Apache software, for example for DAYTIME protocol [DaytimeUDPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/jacoco/org.apache.commons.net.daytime/DaytimeUDPClient.java.html). Then you can interprete the output by help of `SimpleDateFormat`. Another more precise solution would be based on SNTP.